# How to calculate complexity of recursive algorithm in Big O notation?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

The recursive algorithm has complexity:
W(n)=2W(n/2)+ Θ(n)

My solution or guess is O(n).

How to solve that kind of complexity?

Comment: Make another guess, its more than that. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: Is it of n log n complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situations like this are covered by the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). It is also easy to see directly:

```
W(n) = 2 W(n/2) + Theta(n)
     = 2(2 W(n/4) + Theta(n/2)) + Theta(n)
     = 4 W(n/4) + 2 Theta(n)
```

So with each recursion step you get another Theta(n) and the depth of the recursion is log n. The total effort is therefore O(n log n).